# Inverse matching with stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I want to remove all characters which doesn't match a string pattern using `stringr` package. So far I've been able to remove those before the pattern using `"\\w+(?= (grape|satsuma))"` as pattern but remove those after the pattern is still imposible.

```
> str_remove_all("apples grape banana melon olive persimon grape apples satsuma papaya", 
+                "\\w+(?= (grape|satsuma))")
[1] " grape banana melon olive  grape  satsuma papaya"
```

The desired result is:

```
"grape grape satsuma"
```

(**NOTE**: I am aware the easiest approach in this case is to extract only "grape" and "satsuma" but for analysis purposes I prefer this way)

> **Edited** providing the entire problem

The entire problem is as follow, given a `d` data frame which contains a column with a string the function should return the same column only with matches:

```
> d
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  string_column                  c2
  <chr>                       <dbl>
1 apples grape banana satsuma     3
2 grape banana satsuma melon      4
```

Using the answer provided by @d.r works:

```
> d %>% 
+   mutate_at(vars(string_column), ~ gsub("(grape|satsuma| )(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.", "", ., perl = TRUE))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  string_column        c2
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 " grape  satsuma"     3
2 "grape  satsuma "     4
```

All answers provided so far using `stringr` package fail returning the `string_column`

This the `dput` for `d`:

```
d <- structure(list(string_column = c("apples grape banana satsuma", 
"grape banana satsuma melon"), c2 = c(3, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: `gsub("(grape|satsuma| )(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.", "", "apples grape banana melon olive persimon grape apples satsuma papaya", perl = TRUE)`

Comment: @d.b yeah! But I want to use `stringr` package, any idea?

Comment: Using `str_remove_all` with `"\\w+(?= (grape|satsuma))"` as pattern remove words that are before `grape` or `satsuma`. My desire result is that `str_remove_all` erase everything that doesn't match `papaya` or `satsuma`, so the desire result in this case is: `"grape grape satsuma"`. Please, let me know whether the purpose is not clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at [negative lookaheads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) and some related regex techniques in the linked thread.

However, since we are extracting words I'd rather use `str_extract_all` and I'd do it like this:

```
str_extract_all("apples grape banana melon olive persimon grape apples satsuma papaya", 
                               "grape|satsuma")
```

> ```
>  "grape"   "grape"   "satsuma"
> ```

I also really like this line that @steveLangsford left in a comment:

```
paste0(unlist(str_extract_all("apples grape banana melon olive persimon grape apples satsuma papaya", "grape|satsuma")), collapse=" ")
```

> ```
> "grape grape satsuma"
> ```

Taking it a little bit further based on our discussion/comments:

```
string_column <- c("apples grape banana satsuma", "grape banana satsuma melon") 
c2            <- c(3, 4) 
d             <- tibble(string_column,c2) 

myfun <- function(x) {paste0(unlist(str_extract_all(x, "grape|satsuma")), collapse=" ") }

sapply(d$string_column, myfun)
```

> ```
>         "grape satsuma"             "grape satsuma"
> ```

Comment: Using `str_extract_all` solves the problem with the regex expression. However I need to apply this in a column of a data frame so I need that the expression returns only a single string. After trying all around with `str_extract_all` and `str_c` with `map_df ` I assumed the easiest way might be trying to use inverse matching in the regexpression, but it also seems impossible. I've tried several regexpression being `"\\w+(?= (grape|satsuma))"` the closest to my purpose.

Comment: @TitoSanz I see. Let me work on it a bit more over lunch and see if I can add some things to that end.

Comment: paste0(unlist(str_extract_all("apples grape banana melon olive persimon grape apples satsuma papaya", "grape|satsuma")), collapse=" ")

Comment: Let's assume the @steveLangsford 's approach, when I tried to apply along a column in a data frame this return an error:

Comment: @TitoSanz please paste the error maybe it can be applied different. Also the code where you applied it would be good. Meantime I'm looking at an additional approach.

Comment: I tried to apply along a column in a data frame and returned an error: 
'Column `string_column` must be length 2 (the number of rows) or one, not 4'.

The code used is: 
    `string_column <- c("apples grape banana satsuma", "grape banana satsuma melon")  
  
c2 <- c(3, 4)  
  
d <- tibble(string_column,c2)  
  
d %>%   
  mutate_at(vars(string_column),   
            function(x) paste0(unlist(str_extract_all(x, pattern = "grape|satsuma"))))    `

Comment: @TitoSanz `sapply` works; I just made a related edit

Comment: @Hack-R note that this approach doesn't return two rows of a data frame, instead the results are transposed and splitted. First column in both rows must be: `"grape satsuma"`. This is the reason why using `mutate_at` returns that error.

Comment: Also note that the answer provided by @d.b works using:
    `d %>% mutate_at(vars(string_column), ~gsub("(grape|satsuma| )(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.", "", ., perl = TRUE))`

Comment: @TitoSanz with regards to the first comment if you want to transpose it's just `t()` But it sounds like you have a solution with the edit to your code from db so that should be good.